# Extend background-color of header beyond container with css

Tags: css

I have been searching the web for a while now for an answer to my question. I would like to extend a div background-color beyond the div (and the container div as well) so it reaches the width of the browser. Like so http://vinnusal.is/
The problem with the example above is I'm using a padding/margin fix which creates an annoying scroll to the right. I have tried overflow without any luck.

I know this could be done with a container div that is 100% and nesting divs that are smaller. However I would like to use another way if possible, because this is my first shot at a fluid site with all complications that follow.

Thanks in advance,
Helgi

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix"> <!-- Container -->

  <div class="gridContainer clearfix header" id="header"> <!--Header begins--> 
<img src="pics/hvitt.png" alt="VFI Logo" name="logo" id="logo">

<!-- Menu Horizontal -->
... irrelevant markup for menu...

  </div>

  <!-- Header ends -->
<div class="gridContainer clearfix submenu" id="submenu"> <!-- Submenu begins -->
<h1><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="title" -->Articles<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></h1>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 88.626%;
    padding-left: 1.1869%;
    padding-right: 1.1869%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#header {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#submenu {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#article {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#leftColumn {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.6785%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#rightColumn {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.6785%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#header2 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.6785%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 91.4836%;
    padding-left: 0.7581%;
    padding-right: 0.7581%;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#header {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#submenu {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#article {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#leftColumn {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.6574%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#rightColumn {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.6574%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#header2 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.6574%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 78.9565%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.5217%;
    padding-right: 0.5217%;
    margin: auto;
}
#LayoutDiv1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#header {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#submenu {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#article {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#leftColumn {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.3215%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#rightColumn {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.3215%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
}
```

Comment: Please include your current CSS/HTML markup pertaining to this issue. Without it, we can't help you. Also, the container div you mentioned is probably going to be the best way to go about doing this...

Comment: Use a container, it's the right way to do things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I truly appreciate it. I will try to do this with the container.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the `:before` pseudo element with absolute positioning and negative z-index to extend the background color of a contained div the entire way to the edge of the page.

```css
#container {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
}
.stripe {
    background-color:#CCFFFF;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.stripe:before {
    content:"";
    background-color:#CCFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 4000px;
    left: -2000px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>one</div>
  <div class="stripe">two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than sing large values for the `height` and `width` of your `before` element, you can set `left: 0` and `right:: 0` to ensure full coverage of the page without overflowing

Comment: The background  is absolute relative to `.stripe` so that won't work.  `left: 0` and `right: 0` not the right and left side of the page, they are the left and right side of `.stripe`.

Comment: Instead of using very large numbers, you can base the width on the width of the viewport with CSS3 units: `width: 200vw; left: -100vw;`   That will work in modern browsers except for IE 8 and earlier.

Answer (score 19):

Kevin Powell made a Youtube Video about how to do this
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/81pnuZFarRw

All you have to do is add a class to the element and add a couple of lines of CSS! You're basically making a color the whole background and then clipping it based on the element.

CSS

```css
.full-bleed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax red;
  clip-path: inset(0 -100vmax); 
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="full-bleed"></div>
```

Boom, you're done!

Comment: This works great as long as you do not have a sticky or fixed item within it that goes over in height, it won't show or will show cut.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer seems to rely on a fixed height, which I find rare in these days of responsive sites, so building on top of the answer given by Stephen Ostermiller (thanks!) The following code worked for me and surrounds objects of a dynamic height:

```
.container{
  background-color:#000;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.stripe {
  background-color:#000;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
}
.stripe:before {
  content:"";
  background-color:#000;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200vw;
  left: -100vw;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions will cause an overflow.

try this:

```css
.container{
  background-color:#000;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.stripe {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
}
.stripe:before {
  content:"";
  background-color:#000;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the solution for the future readers.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done with one line of code: https://css-tip.com/overflowing-background/

```css
.full-background {
  border-image: conic-gradient(red 0 0) fill 0//0 100vw;
}
```

Full demo

```css
.full-background {
  border-image: conic-gradient(pink 0 0) fill 0//0 100vw;
  padding-block: 10px;
}


section {
  /* center + max-width:800px + min-margin: 10px */
  margin-inline: max(10px, 50% - 800px/2);
  margin-block: 50px; 
}
body {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  background: #eee;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Main title</h1>
  <p>Dragée powder bear claw tiramisu pudding gummi bears wafer. Macaroon chocolate cake cake marzipan icing carrot cake macaroon sweet. Lemon drops </p>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Secondary title</h2>
  <p class="full-background">Pie pastry macaroon candy tootsie roll jujubes pudding pie. Jelly-o chocolate cake pastry gingerbread brownie danish liquorice chocolate cake. Jelly beans donut cupcake danish croissant liquorice. Cotton candy brownie croissant pie toffee. Cotton candy chocolate cake gummi bears ice cream jelly fruitcake caramels. Shortbread ice cream bear claw gingerbread chocolate cake jelly-o cake caramels soufflé.</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h3>another title</h3>
  <p>Pie pastry macaroon candy tootsie roll jujubes pudding pie.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Amazing, worked perfectly. The "//" was giving my formatter an issue though. I replaced the `0//0` with `0/0/0`. I'm sure this is not an issue with your code—just mentioning to help other CSS novices like myself.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this using absolutely positioned div. All we need to do is wrap the element we want to take full width within a relative positioned element and add an absolute div as it's sibling.

```css
.parent {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.child-one {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.child-two-container {
  position: relative;
}

.child-two-background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}

.child-two {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.child-three {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-one">Child one taking width equal to parent</div>
  <div class="child-two-container">
    <div class="child-two-background"></div>
    <div class="child-two">Child two taking full screen width</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child-three">Child three taking width equal to parent</div>
</div>
```